# Breaking an oath(wallah) that i will not sin again by Allah’s name, how do I cancel out this oath?

Tags: oaths

One time I sinned and got really upset, so I swore an oath that i will never sin again(the ones I know), and i am already regretting this decision…
How can i cancel this oath I have made(Wallah) with Allah?

Comment: Assuming you succeed and nullify your oath, do you think that means it will become halal for you to sin?

Answer (score 0):

People swear to force themselves to do or not to do something! But you want to break your promise  and break your oath! You must atone for this quit. This is a penalty for the bad promise man who breaks his oath.
The prescribed punishment for breaking an oath is the release of a slave or the feeding of ten poor people or the covering of ten poor people and, if incapacitated, the fasting for three consecutive days.